# How can load Controller Specific CSS and JS in Ruby On rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.3

In Rails project i am  using Rails 5 version, Has i know controller specific css and js should load automatically without  precompile the code in **development mode**.But if Precompile assets file than all controller specific files are loading.

```
 development.rb file
  Rails.application.configure do
    config.cache_classes = false
    config.eager_load = false
    config.consider_all_requests_local = true
     if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
      config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
      config.cache_store = :memory_store
      config.public_file_server.headers = {
       'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=172800'
      }
    else
     config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
     config.cache_store = :null_store
    end  
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.quiet = true
   config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

end
```

Answer (score 0):

try to make `precompile` false in `development.rb` file:

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

Comment: Thank You for Reply , If add this assets it self not loading